# Subtract dates in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have two DateField variables and I would like to subtract them and return the difference as a number of months to the nearest month. How might I do this?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: How long is one of your "months"?

Comment: One month would be 30 days, thanks.

Comment: I recently found relativedelta in the python-dateutil package.  It is quite useful for doing these sorts of things: http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-ba5ffd4df8111d1b83fc194b97ebecf837add454

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a definite answer using calendar month lengths:

```
months = lambda a, b: abs((a.year - b.year) * 12 + a.month - b.month)
```

Example:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> a = datetime.date(2011, 2, 8)
>>> b = datetime.date(2010, 5, 14)
>>> months(a, b)
9
```

Edit, if you want to round based on days too:

```
months = lambda a, b: abs((a.year - b.year) * 12 + a.month - b.month) + int(abs(a.day - b.day) > 15)
```

Example:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> a = datetime.date(2011, 2, 8)
>>> b = datetime.date(2010, 5, 14)
>>> months(a, b)
9
>>> b = datetime.date(2010, 5, 30)
>>> months(a, b)
10
```

Comment: You should consider using date difference and a `timedelta` object instead.

Comment: The other answer used a `timedelta` object, but since it only has resolution in days (and the month/year information is lost at this point) there doesn't seem to be any way to get the actual calendar month difference. Dividing by 30 is only an approximation and error will accumulate over long timespans.

Answer (score 6):

Datefields are datetime.date instances.  You can directly subtract them which will give you a [timedelta](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta).  You can access the number of days a timedelta represents via timedelta.days. Lets say the datefield self.date is set to two months ago:

```
today = datetime.date.today()
n = today - self.date
months = int(n.days/30)
```

should give you the number of months in this case 2.  Depending on how you define the nearest month you may need to round rather than casting to an int.

Answer (score 0):

```
def date_diff:
now = datetime.now().date()
s=seo_job.job_end_date.replace(hour=23,minute=59,second=59).date()
#seo_job.job_end_date an end date that is saved in db
return (now-s)
```